# did the machine break/ was the machine broken

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was buying coffee today and the staff tole me that they couldn't make coffee at the time.

If I wanted to know the reason and I suspected it was because of the coffee machine. Are these three following sentences equivalent?

1. did the machine break?
2. was the machine broken?
3. is the machine broken?

Answer (score 2):

1 and 3 are both good.

If *broken* is understood as an adjective, 2 doesn’t work if you’re asking at the time you’re unable to get coffee. You want to know if it *is* broken. But if it’s understood as a past participle then it’s fine (“was it broken” is like “was it broken by somebody”). Since *broken* is more likely to be understood as an adjective then I would avoid asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

In this context you would use #3, is the machine broken?

- Person A: Sorry we can't serve coffee at the moment
- You: Is the machine broken? (you want to know why, the current state)

Other context for #1 and #2...

- Person A: I was trying to replace the water filter but you'll never guess what happened next!
- You: did the machine break? (what happened)
- Person A: I *was* trying to make coffee, but I couldn't
- You: was the machine broken? (past tense / state)